# Inside create form, how do I route to a nested resource? 'route' => 'user.lesson.store' doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've created a nested resource in my routes.php

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
Route::resource('user.lesson', 'LessonController');
Route::resource('user.lesson.hotspot', 'HotspotController');
```

And I've tied all user resource actions to the User controller.  I've moved on to Lesson, and I'm trying to create a form to create a new lesson.

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'user.lesson.store')); }}
    {{ Form::label('title', 'Title of lesson'); }}
    {{ Form::text('title'); }}
    {{ Form::label('description', 'Description of lesson'); }}
    {{ Form::textarea('description'); }}
    {{ Form::submit('Create New Lesson'); }}
{{ Form::close(); }}
```

However, this produces an action of `.../user/%7Buser%7D/lesson`.  Pointing route at `lesson.store` produces an error.

What else do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the route with the user key, as the route name that laravel generates will be like `user/{user}/lesson/{lesson}`

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('user.lesson.store', $user->getKey()))); }}
```